# Compilation of Delphi Project with Final Builder

Tags: path, compilation, delphi

I have a big Delphi project organized like this (simplified):

```
Sources:
    Delphi:  
        Project A
        Project B
        …
        Project G
        COMMON
    FinalBuilder
LIB:
    Lib A
    Lib B
    …
    Lib K
```

So, each `Project` folder contains the files (`.dprog`, `.pas` and `.dfm`) needed for the project. The `COMMON` folder contains the files (`.pas`) used by more than one project. And the `Lib` folders contain external resources (`.pas`and `.dfm`) also needed for more than one project
Then in `FinalBuilder` I have my `ProjectBuilder.fbp8` and `Project.ini` files.

The idea is, the ProjectBuilder will ask me which project i want to compile (and some more options), and compile them - one after another.

However, there is some problem with the Library Path.

See, each Delphi Project contains the path to its needed files in `Project X` and `COMMON`, but **not** the path to the needed files in `LIB`. So if I wanted to compile the Delphi project using only Delphi IDE, it won't work (until I give it the Library Path). However, I want to compile using FinalBuilder, and this particular path is given by FinalBuilder (through his `.ini` file).

So, the ProjectBuilder will get all the variables needed for the Project I want to build from its .ini file, including the Library Path, and then launch a "Build Delphi" action with this Library Path correctly setted.

But, for some reason, it doesn't work: compilation fail saying it couldn't find the units which should be given by the Library path. So i guess there is somewhere a miscommunication between FinalBuilder and the Delphi Project which leads to the Delphi Project not having the Library Path (but i have no idea how this "Build Delphi" action works in details).

Maybe there's some more settings to do in FinalBuilder? Does anyone knows about it? Or it comes from the fact that those files are loaded as a Library, and not as source files?

Comment: This is a really simple issue since the references for each unit you need is mentioned in .dproj file. Then you can easily compile each project without add library path. Just keep common files in the same folder and click Add File to Project. If you can not do it send me an e-mail or request suport in Skype ricardodarocha@outlook.com

Comment: Common files are not a problem here; Delphi is told where to find them (it's like `foo in "../COMMON"`). The problem is the files who are not in COMMON but in a lot of separate folders external to the project. I'm not going to go search for them and add them one by one to each prog; it may work, but adding the path directly into Delphi would have the same effect and be really faster. 
My point is, I know how to add them to the Delphi project, but I'm not supposed to do this. FB8 get the Path and should give it to delphi within the `Build Delphi`action. I need to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: I've refactored the question to make it more simple and clear, if that could help. I've tried to compile one Project in Delphi IDE (after giving it the needed Library Path) and it works well. I just need it to get this path through FinalBuilder, so I won't have to add those paths to every single Project...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using an old version of FinalBuilder that pre-dates Delpjhi 10.2 - you need to update to a newer version.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's impossible to know how to compile something that will be released years in the future - (I work on FinalBuilder) - OP I recommend you contact  FinalBuilder support.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I don't think that's the problem: In the source code, I have this `ProjectBuilder.fbp8` file, which clearly says I have to use FB8; and the dev told me that i had to use Delphi 10. Which mean it's working on his computer with those two together.

Comment: Not all FinalBuilder 8 versions support Delphi 10.x we add support for new delphi versions as they are released - what compiler versions are listed on the Delphi action project tab? You need to select the compiler version that matches the compiler you are using.

Comment: I selected Delphi 10.2 Tokyo on the Delphi action project tab, which is the one I'm using. However, the general tab says that the action supports compiling Delphi 3 to XE8. But as far as I know, the dev uses Delphi 10.2 and Final Builder 8, and it's working fine on his computer. Could it be that i need a newer version of Final Builder 8?